# How to get a path to a Dropbox file in order to use the files_download function in python?

Tags: python, dropbox

As a newbie in python I'm trying to download a single file from my dropbox account. I've got the Dropbox token from developer account and I am not getting how can I use this token in python code. Moreover, I  have no idea how can I get a Dropbox path to download files. The code is following:

```
def download_file():
        dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(DROPBOXTOKEN)
        # Check that the access token is valid
        try:
            dbx.users_get_current_account()
        except AuthError as err:
            sys.exit("ERROR: Invalid access token; try re-generating an access token from the app console on the web.")
        with open("//", "w") as f:
            metadata, res = dbx.files_download(path=DROPPATH)
            f.write(res.content)
```

Please guide me in detail how can I use here dropbox access token and how to get dropbox path

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to open a file from your Dropbox account.
"Prime_Numbers.txt" is an example of a sample file located in dropbox.
Could you please modify your code to something like this?

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("<ACCESS_TOKEN>")

with open("Prime_Numbers.txt", "wb") as f:
    metadata, res = dbx.files_download(path="/Homework/math/Prime_Numbers.txt")
    f.write(res.content)
```

You can find how to locate your dropbox file path depending on your system by reading this article. https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/locate-dropbox-folder

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I use access token first?
Afterwards, How can I get such path from dropbox like to download file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zruhdc88o62axxg/intro.docx?dl=0

Comment: Please follow this documentation to get your access token : http://99rabbits.com/get-dropbox-access-token/

Comment: Hey! I have generated access token but I have a question I am not getting how to use access token by using python as a newbie. That's what I am asking you.